# clean way to implement similar enum types in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have multiple enum types, a typical implementation is as follows.

```
public enum SomeType {
    TYPE_A("aaa"),
    TYPE_B("bbb"),

    private final String type;

    private SomeType(String type) { this.type = type; }

    public boolean equals(String otherType) {
        return (otherType == null) ? false : type.equals(otherType.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Other than specific enum types, the constructor and methods (i.e., equals and a few more) are the same for these enums. I cant create a super "class" and extends from it. Is there a clean solution so that I only need 1 copy of these methods and make all enum types inherit them? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enum types are permitted to implement interfaces, like any other class.  An example in Java SE is [StandardCopyOption](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html) and [LinkOption](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/LinkOption.html), which both implement [CopyOption](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/CopyOption.html).

Although CopyOption doesn't have any methods, you certainly can define methods in such an inherited interface if you wish.

```
public interface TypedValue {
    String getType();

    default boolean equals(String otherType) {
        return otherType != null && getType().equals(otherType.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

```
public enum SomeType
implements TypedValue {
    TYPE_A("aaa"),
    TYPE_B("bbb");

    private final String type;

    private SomeType(String type) { this.type = type; }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Comment: We should not forget to emphasize how dangerous method signatures, that can easily mixed up with the inherited `Object.equals` but have a different meaning, are…

Comment: @Holger Agreed.  equals(TypeOtherThanObject) is a practice that the designers of Java SE learned early on was a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 you can do something like this:

```
interface TypeChecker {

    default boolean equals(String otherType) {
        return otherType != null && otherType.toUpperCase().equals(toString());
    }
}
```

Then you just need

```
enum SomeType implements TypeChecker {
    AAA, BBB
}
```

The drawback of this approach is that enum constants cannot have names that are different from their `type` strings. One workaround is to override `toString` for individual constants (or use a method other than `toString` as in VGR's solution). The problem with doing that is that it doesn't really cut down on the boilerplate.